# Strange JS behavior when handling "that" inside an each function

Tags: javascript

I've noticed an unusual behavior when developing using javascript, can someone explain that to me?

I have this a javascript code:

```
function MyFunction(){
   var categoryId = 'abc';
   var that = this;
   $(_elem).parent().find('[data-id]').each(function(){
   that.categoryId += $(this).data('id') + ',';
   });
   setEventsCategoryEx(categoryId, url, parentUrl);
}
```

This **should** be wrong, because categoryId is not global, so it should not be accessible using "that.categoryId".

The issue is:
When the execution first enters in the each method, outputting
that.categoryId would generate "abc" (the value I assigned to the local categoryId variable).

When the mouse leaves the each function, that.categoryId and categoryId have different values:
categoryId = "abc"
that.categoryId = "abc+"

I do not understand the following: they should be separated variables, why do they start with the same value?

thanks,
Oscar

Edit: sorry, when coppying and pasting I forgot to add the function declaration. It is inside a function that is called by an "onclick" event.

Comment: what scope is this code executing in?

Comment: if you can access this.categoryId, why wouldn't you be able to access that.categoryId? (same object)

Comment: @jbabey sorry, I forgot to add the scope. It is inside a function, please see the edit for more details.

Comment: @robbieAreBest sorry, I didn't quite understood your comment. The reason for this question is to understand why the two variables have the same initial value (even though I just assigned it to one of them) and different final values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't inside a function then `var categoryId = 'abc'` has the same effect as `window.categoryId = 'abc'`.

If you aren't inside a function, then `this` is `window`

So what you see is expected behaviour.

See [your js console for this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Euvz9/)

> Edit: sorry, when coppying and pasting I forgot to add the function declaration. It is inside a function that is called by an "onclick" event.

After your edit, [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Euvz9/1/).

Comment: ^^this. And they have different values after execution, obviously, because variables in JS are not passed by reference

Comment: Strict mode would be good here, it's quite bad to get implicit global for `this` when you are not in an object context.

Comment: Not merely "if you aren't inside a function", but rather "if you don't have an explicit object context" (e.g., from calling the function as a member function of an object or passing a context into `call` or `apply`.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt hm, got it, but why do they have the same initial value?

Comment: @oscar because in global scope, `this` refers to `window`. And when you define global variables, they are defined as properties of `window`, too. So, since you're setting your `that` variable to `this`, you're setting it to `window`. And `categoryId` is a property of `window`, because you defined it in global scope. So, in your case, when it starts out, `this.categoryId == that.categoryId == categoryId`'

Comment: @Quentin in response to your edit (which was in response to the OP's edit), if you attach a function to onclick like this: `<div id="hi" onclick="Foo()"/>`, then you are simply attaching the *call* to the function to the element. If you use `element.onclick = foo`, you're attaching the function itself, and thus the function is in the context of the element. I would guess you tried it using the latter of the two ways I just stated.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html), specifically the part about copying vs referring

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt — But either way, `var categoryId = 'abc';` will be scoped to the function and not to the `window` or the HTMLElementNode.

Comment: @Quentin I referenced using onclick="MyFunction()". if I write "this" in my Firebug Console, I get Window as an output

Comment: @Oscar — Yes, `this` is `window` if you call a function directly (not as a method) as well as when you put code outside any function.

Comment: @Quentin With onclick="Function()", it's in global scope. When you reference it that way the function is called straight from the window, thus any variables declared inside will be in `window`'s scope. Try it and see.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt — No, variables declared inside the function (using `var`) will be scoped to the function: http://jsfiddle.net/q395t/ Inside the function `this` will be `window`, but the value of `this` doesn't determine the scope of new variables that are declared.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function that is not being used as a method in non-strict mode, then `this` is the global object.

[Section 11.2.3 of the language spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3) says:

> The production *CallExpression* `:` *MemberExpression* *Arguments* is evaluated as follows:
>
> ```
> 6. If Type(ref) is Reference, then
>      If IsPropertyReference(ref) is true, then
>        Let thisValue be GetBase(ref).
>    Else, the base of ref is an Environment Record
>      Let thisValue be the result of calling the ImplicitThisValue concrete method of GetBase(ref).
> ```